# Term For Details Involved In Production

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a term/word for all details involved in the production of an item (ex: machinery used, settings,  material, size)?

Comment: What have you already considered, and why were they not suitable?

Comment: There's a phrase: *all aspects of*.  "all details involved" sounds like a *logistics* problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Specification**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specifications)

> a detailed description of work to be done or materials to be used in a project : an instruction that says exactly how to do or make something